# How can you sort data validation input list in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Given the following data validation setup I can only select foods in the way I entered them in the list of foods column. Is there a way to sort these before I'm able to select those?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Why can't you sort the list of foods column before doing the data validation?

Comment: Because it's already sorted differently (pasta, dairy, fruits, supplements, etc..)

Comment: I tried to sort it in the last tab alfabetically by copying the list using =ARRAYFORMULA('List of foods'!B:B). And then sorting that list (but that gives circular dependency error..)

Comment: Can you try just copy/pasting (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V to get only values and thus not create any dependency) the list and try the sorting again? Of course, you will then need to change the range reference of the validation.

Comment: I could do that but then I would always have to manually update the sorted list of foods when I add new foods to the regular list of foods. I want it to update instantly

Comment: But I guess it's not possible then @Jerry?

Comment: How does a PivotTable sound? You can make a pivottable that auto updates when more data is inserted into a list it references, and you can choose to sort it alphabetically. [Picture example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8H9ps.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a PivotTable to help you:

1. Select the field containing the list and go to 'Data' > 'Pivot table report...'
2. Click 'Add field' for 'Rows' and pick the field in the dropdown. Ensure that the order is ascending, that the 'Show totals' is unchecked (or else, you'll get 'Grand Total' in your validation) and that the option is to update the table on each change:

[image]

Note: You usually get the pivot table in a different sheet. You can copy/paste the data in that new sheet and change the source data by clicking on 'Edit range...' like I did in the picture above, then delete the initial sheet.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this formula to automatically sort the data you're entering:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A500))
```

Enter this formula into another column, or another sheet, and use that range instead as the source for your data validation.

Comment: Nice simple way to achieve the desired result. +1

Comment: Definitely the easiest way - it's a bit of a shame that Sheets doesn't just allow you to enter array-based formulas into the data validation range though.