# How to display numbers in ascending order in data validation even after selection?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I've made a drop down list of numbers from 1 to 104 in range A1:A104 with Data validation.

The issue I get is the following:

After I select a number from the list and populate the output cell, the list then sort from the next multiple of 10.

Here's a screenshot of the issue:
[image]

I tested the 2 solutions from this prior question but they don't resolve the issue:[How can you sort data validation input list in google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917210/how-can-you-sort-data-validation-input-list-in-google-spreadsheet)

The multiple of 10 still follows instead of the ascending or next unit number order.
Is there a way to make it sort the list in ascending order or next unit even after selection?

EDIT1:
[Test sheet as requested](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sQwBkmXWOgcXcCWWRuQaAzw6q87s0mlo_1V8XL-giY4/edit?usp=sharing)

EDIT2:
It does sort in ascending order for strings/month text and from thousands/years:

[image: TEXT SORTING]

[image: FROM THOUSANDS SORTING]

Why not regular digits?

Comment: Please share a test sheet.

Comment: @marikamitsos Here it is Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
*(following OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759307/how-to-display-numbers-in-ascending-order-in-data-validation-even-after-selectio/63759518?noredirect=1#comment112748433_63759518))*

> *Thanks @marikamitsos It does sort in ascending order for strings/month text and from thousands/years. Why not for regular digits?*

As you can see in the image, **the same priority is followed for text as well** as with digits.

[image]

---

Unfortunately you cannot.
It is just the way Google Sheets return results giving priority to your search terms.
Do notice the **bolded digits**.

That is why you see this:

[image]

OR even this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @marikamitsos
It does sort in ascending order for strings/month text and from thousands/years.
Why not for regular digits?
Is there a work around?

Comment: *"Is there a work around?"*. I am afraid not. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So only 'dates' formats have ascending order bypassing the search priority?

Comment: Dates are unique. And that is the only reason. You see, in our examples, values like `wh`, `10`, `8` are not unique.

Comment: Ok. Thank a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Drop-down lists attempt something akin to auto-fill, i.e., once you type something, "closest matches" appear toward the top of the list, getting ruled out as you type more.

My question would be this: why have a drop-down for numbers 1 to 104 in the first place? Wouldn't it be easier and take less time to use a custom formula for the data validation, e.g.:

```
=AND(A3>=1,A3<=104)
```

... and then just set it to Reject any other input?

You could use cell-contained instructions if necessary, or even use the "Show validation help text" option in the data-validation window.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Erik Tyler i wasn't aware it works on the closest matches basis. I won't need the data validation any more. It's indeed faster just to type the data for my use!